# Gitlab Ci runner using outdated image

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Im fighting with topic whole day and have no clue what i'm doing wrong.

In our CI/CD we have stage where we using image from our registry on gitlab instance, and this stage is using outdated image.

Its change only when i intentionally change the image tag (and no im not using latest tag)

Runner is on Kubernetes, but i don't have access to his configuration.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you using gitlab.com or a self-hosted instance? Are you using your own runners, or shared runners (if gitlab.com)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default Kubernetes behavior. It will pull the image just if it doesn't exist yet or always if the image tag is latest.

You should either tag the image with the commit on every change or pull the image manually after updating it.

On the other hand, if you have access to the gitlab runner config, you should be able to edit the `imagePullPolicy` of the pods created. Refer to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images for possible values.